Android Studio, I can't activate Notifications, after I declined it
What I want to do is create a SwitchCompat button that controls the application notification, when an User activates this button, I want to send him/her a notification saying "Do you want to get notifications from this app" and if user clicks on "yes" I want to activate notifications. Everything is good but after user clicks either yes or no, I can't change the settings of the notifications, so the user can not close or open after his/her desicion, which is not I want.
XML File
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/notificationSwitch"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:switchMinWidth="50dp"
android:theme="@style/NotificationSwitchTheme"/>

AndroidManifest.XML
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

Java File
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "notification_channel";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION = 100;
private SwitchCompat notificationSwitch;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
private static final String PREF_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED = "notification_enabled";

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_tab);

    notificationSwitch = findViewById(R.id.notificationSwitch);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Check the switch button status
    boolean isNotificationEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, false);
    notificationSwitch.setChecked(isNotificationEnabled);

    createNotificationChannel();

    notificationSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SettingsActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SettingsActivity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS},
                                REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION);
                    }
                    else {
                        showNotification();
                        saveNotificationPreference(true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    showNotification();
                    saveNotificationPreference(true);
                }
            }
            else {
                saveNotificationPreference(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
//Outside of the onCreate

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            showNotification();
            saveNotificationPreference(true);
        }
        else {
            notificationSwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Notification Channel";
        String description = "Channel for notification";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_permission))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_alert))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}

private void saveNotificationPreference(boolean isEnabled) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, isEnabled);
    editor.apply();
}

I know there are no comments, first I wanted to complete the functionality of the code, then I will add the comments.
